# Arquivo txt não é encontrado ao gerar arquivo .jar

Tags: java, arquivo

Tenho uma aplicação em Java, essa aplicação possui imagens, e tive o mesmo problema: ao gerar o arquvo .jar(executável) as imagens não apareciam, porém se rodasse direto no NetBeans, ela aparecia. Resolvi o problema botando a imagem dentro de uma pasta que criei (dados) dentro da pasta scr, e no código eu fiz:

```
new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/dados/img.jpg"));
```

Isso resolveu o problema, agora o negócio é com arquivo .txt, como faço isso? Preciso ler um txt, no NetBeans ele encontra o arquivo certinho, porém no arquivo jar gerado não é encontrado

EDIT

```
File arq = new File("src/dados/arq.txt");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Se o `txt` está dentro do jar, [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) não irá funcionar, porque o arquivo txt só existe dentro do jar, e não existe fora dele, pois `File` trabalha com endereços(URL) de arquivos no sistema operacional corrente. Para isso, resgate usando o seguinte:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/dados/arq.txt");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Depois é só varrer o [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) usando um laço de repetição.

**Referencia:**

[How to read a file from a jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2271947/5524514)

[Including a text file inside a jar file and reading it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10452844/5524514)

Comment: Funcionou obrigado