# Criar JAR com um txt incluso

Tags: java

Tenho um programa que salva os contatos em um arquivo simples de txt, porem quando quero executar o jar em outra maquina (gero o jar utilizando o package for store do netbeans), quando executo em outra maquina ele não acha o txt.

No android eu consigo fazer isso colocando o arquivo txt dentro da pasta assets, no java li algo sobre `ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();` mas não consegui também.

Para fazer isso eu devo colocar o txt em alguma ´pasta especifica ou ´é de outra maneira?

Comment: Tente alterar seu código, de forma que se ele não encontrar o arquivo, ele crie um novo e passe a usa-lo. Dessa forma, em cada maquina ele criará um txt diferente. Agora se o objetivo é ter o txt em comum com varias maquinas, creio que este não seja o melhor caminho, talvez um banco de dados seja melhor.

Comment: Veja essa questão aqui, um problema parecido com o seu. [Arquivo txt não é encontrado ao gerar arquivo .jar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100874/arquivo-txt-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-encontrado-ao-gerar-arquivo-jar?rq=1)

Comment: fiz usando ftp. obrigado